# How to draw text in centre of circle in the max font size possible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have a Circle which I draw on a button. The button can be sized based on the layout.
Now I am looking for some code to help in drawing text in the middle of circle in a font size which best fits the text in the circle.

I cannot set the font size for the text as the dimensions of the button change as per layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `onGlobalLayoutListener` to you button:

```
myButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Here your button is added to layout and has it's height and width
                    }
                });
```

According to it's width you can try to set its font size.

```
myButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, [SIZE]);
```

just note, that size of the button in that listener you will get in pixels, so you need to set text size in pixels too.